# How to create dynamic framework which uses another framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, cocoapods, building

First of all I can't use Cocoapods.

My framework uses SocketRocket, I have its .framework file.

It's fine if the client has to manually add both my framework and SocketRocket.framework, I don't want to use an umbrella framework.

The problem is my framework depends on SocketRocket, but

```
#import <SocketRocket/SocketRocket.h>
```

doesn't work.

My framework doesn't add SocketRocket to the "Link Binary With Libraries" phase, I just added SocketRocket.framework's path to "Framework Search Paths". I think that should be enough for it to find the headers and the symbols.

I haven't found a guide about creating a framework which depends on another framework, everybody seems to be using CocoaPods.

Answer (score 2):

You should add SocketRocket.framework into your header search paths too. And if your library is using SocketRocket.framework, you should link your library against it. Otherwise, you'll get linker errors.

Also, you should embed SocketRocket.framework into your application target. If you don't, your app will crash when it tries to load SocketRocket.framework with "image not found" error.

You can embed SocketRocket.framework under your target's Build Phases -> "Embed Frameworks" phase. If you don't have that phase, you can create it "New Copy File Phase" button.

[image]

And then selecting "Frameworks" as destination:

[image]